# Should you tag/flag an object or move it to a different collection?

Tags: data-structures, collections

When you need to classify an object; what are the design implications for using a collection vs a member field (say a Boolean flag).

So say I have a `Client` object, `Client` is either 'active' or 'archived'. 
Should I have two collections one for 'active clients' and the other for 'archived clients' and move objects from active to archived, or a single collection of clients where each client has an `isActive` flag?

An answer with appropriate tradeoffs of either technique is preferable, since I'm about to implement one and I don't understand the implications between them.

Comment: see [What is the problem with "Pros and Cons"?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)

Comment: @gnat I need to make a judgment based on tradeoffs I can't yet see or understand. Any tips on rephrasing the question, or a place to look other than StackExchange is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to make a judgment based on tradeoffs I can't yet see or understand.

Then postpone the decision as much as you can (hide an implementation behind some getter / setter) until you understand the other uses and the tradeoffs enough to commit a design.